# "dpkg -i mysql-5.5.25-ubuntu10.04-x86_64.deb" not installing anything?

Tags: installation, dpkg, install-from-source

I has been logged in as root

I want to install MySQL 5.5 in Ubuntu 10.04.

When browsing `tar.gz` for source installing, I found DEB release `mysql-5.5.25-ubuntu10.04-x86_64.deb` in [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=408381#mirrors) for Ubuntu. So, I simply download it.

But I not familiar with dpkg

When I run `dpkg -i mysql-5.5.25-ubuntu10.04-x86_64.deb`, it not install anything. No MySQL directory created, and also no init file created

Running `whereis mysql` give nothing

Below is what we can see when I run dpkg:

```
myserver:~/sourceinstaller# dpkg -i mysql-5.5.25-ubuntu10.04-x86_64.deb
Selecting previously deselected package mysql.
(Reading database ... 25178 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mysql (from mysql-5.5.25-ubuntu10.04-x86_64.deb) ...
Setting up mysql (5.5.25) ...
myserver:~/sourceinstaller#
```

I don't know what I've just missed.

Comment: Is there any directory like `/opt/mysql` ?

Comment: Oh.. Yes. It's there. I'm sorry I'm totally noob. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to start the mysql server by `/opt/mysql/server5.5/bin/mysqld start` and add the line `export PATH="/opt/mysql/server5.5/bin:$PATH"` to `/root/.profile`. 
Though you should not be doing administrative task by entering root account, use `sudo` before your commands instead. Also, the `mysql` server and client both are available in Ubuntu Software Centre.